# Mysql left join multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have a database which stores information about cars. There are 3 tables which don't have foreign keys:

make(make_ID, name,..)

colour(colour_ID,c_name,...)

engine(engine_ID,eng_size,...)

There's a 4th table which connects all the others together using foreign keys(FK):

carDetails(CarDetails_ID, CD_make_ID, CD_colorID,...)

Now I would like to use left joins to retrieve the appropriate information from tables about a car by using the IDs in the query.

Ideally I would like to select the make.name WHERE make.make_ID = carDetails.CD_make_ID etc. and keep joining extra information on the left. I have tried this and i'm getting errors on the 'where' clause...apparently it cannot be recognized.

```
SELECT name FROM make WHERE 'make.make_ID' = 'carDetails.CD_make_ID' LEFT JOIN colour.name WHERE colour.colour_ID = carDetails.CD_colour_ID
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the query you are currently using?

Comment: So far I only have the following...SELECT name
FROM `make` 
WHERE 'make.make_ID' = 'carDetails.CD_make_ID'
LEFT JOIN `colour.name`
WHERE colour.colour_ID = carDetails.CD_colour_ID

Comment: Take a look at daniel's answer. The issue with your query is that you are trying to specify WHERE, but you haven't given your query `carDetails` yet. You have to do your joins to get that data first before you can drill down using where/like/etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT name FROM make, carDetails WHERE 'make.make_ID' = 'carDetails.CD_make_ID' LEFT JOIN colour.name ON colour.colour_ID = carDetails.CD_colour_ID
```